# Tasks fail after BAM admin password change

Tags: wso2

After changing the default password for *admin* user in WSO2 BAM 4.1.0, tasks fail with the following error:

```
TID: [0] [BAM] [2013-06-20 16:56:15,464] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.impl.HiveExecutorServiceImpl} -  Error while executing Hive script.
Query returned non-zero code: 9, cause: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapRedTask {org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.impl.HiveExecutorServiceImpl}
java.sql.SQLException: Query returned non-zero code: 9, cause: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapRedTask
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveStatement.executeQuery(HiveStatement.java:189)
        at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.impl.HiveExecutorServiceImpl$ScriptCallable.call(HiveExecutorServiceImpl.java:355)
        at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.impl.HiveExecutorServiceImpl$ScriptCallable.call(HiveExecutorServiceImpl.java:250)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
TID: [0] [BAM] [2013-06-20 16:56:15,467] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.task.HiveScriptExecutorTask} -  Error while executing script : am_stats_analyzer_460 {org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.ta
sk.HiveScriptExecutorTask}
org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.exception.HiveExecutionException: Error while executing Hive script.Query returned non-zero code: 9, cause: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hado
op.hive.ql.exec.MapRedTask
        at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.impl.HiveExecutorServiceImpl.execute(HiveExecutorServiceImpl.java:117)
        at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.task.HiveScriptExecutorTask.execute(HiveScriptExecutorTask.java:60)
        at org.wso2.carbon.ntask.core.impl.TaskQuartzJobAdapter.execute(TaskQuartzJobAdapter.java:56)
        at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:213)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Reverting back the password to its original value solves the issue.

How do I change the password for the *admin* user and keep the tasks working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to solve the issue I had to perform the following steps:

- edit the file `[BAM_HOME]/repository/conf/etc/cassandra-auth.xml` and change the `password` value to the **new password**.
- edit the file `[BAM_HOME]/repository/conf/datasources/master-datasources.xml` and change the `password` value of the `WSO2BAM_CASSANDRA_DATASOURCE` datasource to the **new password**.
- restart the BAM: the Hive tasks now run without errors.

where the **new password** is the password I assigned to the *admin user*.

Moreover, the *Main \ Manage \ Cassandra Keyspaces \ List* page in the BAM UI, which was raising the following error, is now fixed:

```
org.wso2.carbon.cassandra.mgt.ui.CassandraAdminClientException: Error retrieving keyspace names !
(...)
Caused by: org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: InvalidRequestException(why:You have not logged in)
(...)
```

Answer (score 3):

Have you changed the username, password in the hive script am_stats_analyzer? The defaults are admin/admin, check the hive script and update the password accordingly. The property is as follows;

"cassandra.ks.username" = "admin",
"cassandra.ks.password" = "xxxxx",

Check if that fixes your issue.

Comment: Where is this file located? I cannot find it in the `/opt/wso2/wso2bam-2.3.0` folder.

Comment: I tried to reconfigure this file `repository/conf/advanced/hive-rss-config.xml`, but I still get the error.

Comment: From this source file `http://wso2.org/svn/browse/wso2/carbon/platform/branches/4.1.0/products/apimgt/1.4.0/modules/distribution/product/src/main/statistics/API_Manager_Analytics/analytics/am_stats_analyzer?view=diff&r1=169799&r2=169800&pathrev=169800` it seems that the password is stored in a database.

Comment: Hello Shariq, although the answer didn't solve the issue right away, you pointed me to the right direction, and I really appreciate that you spent some time trying to help. Therefore I am giving you the bounty, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I couldn't follow up with the question earlier, anyway glad your problem is sorted now .! Keep on trying BAM and don't hesitate to holler if you run into any issues.

Thanks,
Shariq.